# pycharm highlights the code ax.set_zlabel('Z')

Tags: matplotlib, pycharm

I want to know why IDE pycharm(2018.1.1) highlighting the code ax.set_zlabel('Z')
with hint *unresolved attribute reference 'set_zlabel' for class Axes*
but the code run normally.
these are import packages

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import pairwise_distances_argmin
```

Comment: Can you share the rest of the code?

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, PyCharm doesn't complain for me with the following code, but I'm guessing that's an effect of a newer version (I'm using matplotlib 3.0.0 and PyCharm 2018.1.4).

In any case, I believe the problem comes from the fact that PyCharm might not know that e.g. `add_subplot()` can return different objects depending on the projection used.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
type(ax1)
>>> matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
type(ax1)
>>> matplotlib.axes._subplots.Axes3DSubplot
```

However, you can help PyCharm by providing "type hints" (see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html)

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")  # type: Axes3D
ax1.set_zlabel("z-label")
```

or, if using Python 3+:

```
ax1: Axes3D = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
```